# Updated background color Selector Android Studio

Tags: android

everyone I am finalizing my App before publishing, and the last thing I need to resolve is to change the background color of this pop up.

Nothing I've tried works. There are multiple list selectors in our app and all get this white background.

I've updated popupTheme, Dialog Alerts, nothing seems to get this background. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated!

[image: pop up bg]